# Log Parser subtracting 5 from UTC

Tags: .net, iis, logging, iis-7, logparser

How can i convert the time into UTC-5 . Currently my time is in UTC but i want to subtract 5 hours from that time.

```
LogParser.exe "SELECT QUANTIZE(TO_LOCALTIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time)), 3600) AS Hour,  COUNT(*) AS Hits  FROM D:\projects\jetstar\deployed\u_ex150628.log WHERE date>'2015-06-27' and date<'2015-06-29' and cs-uri-query LIKE '%%orig%%' Group By Hour" -o:datagrid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

IT is using the `Sub` function.

```
LogParser.exe "SELECT  SUB( QUANTIZE(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time), 3600),TIMESTAMP('05:00:00', 'hh:mm:ss'))  AS HOUR,  COUNT(*) AS Hits  FROM D:\projects\jetstar\deployed\u_ex150628.log WHERE date>'2015-06-27' and date<'2015-06-29' and cs-uri-query LIKE '%%orig%%' Group By Hour" -o:datagrid
```

Comment: Correct. Another way is: SUB(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time), 18000)

Answer (score 1):

The answer above didn't work for me. QUANTIZE got rid of the minutes.
Here's what I used

```
SUB(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time), TIMESTAMP('05:00:00', 'hh:mm:ss'))
```

If you want it as a string

```
To_String(SUB(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time), TIMESTAMP('05:00:00', 'hh:mm:ss')), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```